# How to use hibernate criteria to return only one element of an object instead the entire object?

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I'm trying to get only the list of id of object bob for example instead of the list of bob. It's ok with a HQL request, but I would know if it's possible using criteria ?

An example :

```
final StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
hql.append( "select bob.id from " )
    .append( bob.class.getName() ).append( " bob " )
    .append( "where bob.id > 10");

final Query query = session.createQuery( hql.toString() );
return query.list();
```

Answer (score 47):

I think you could do that with Projections, something like

```
Criteria.forClass(bob.class.getName())
        .add(Restrictions.gt("id", 10))
        .setProjection(Projections.property("id"))
        );
```

Answer (score 20):

Similarly you can also:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(bob.class);

criteria.add(Expression.gt("id", 10));

criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));

criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));

return criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 8):

or setProjection(Projections.id())

Answer (score 2):

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Hibernate-Criteria-Queries-in-Depth/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory;    
Criteria crit=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Model.class);
crit.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
List result = crit.list();
```

This code code will give you list of ids in the model class like `[1,2,3]`.
if you wants to get the array list like `[{"id":1},{"id":2}]` then use the following code

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory;    
Criteria crit=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Model.class); 
crit.setProjection(Projections.property("id").as("id")); 
List result = crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option (though a bit un hibernate-esque) is to use "raw" sql, like this:

```
List<Long> myList = session.createSQLQuery("select single_column from table_name")
          .addScalar("single_column", StandardBasicTypes.LONG).list();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that like this

```
    bob bb=null;

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(bob.class);  
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",id));

    bb = (bob) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

as Restrictions you can add your condition

Comment: Is not the answer to the question, but it was usuful to me