# Hibernate Query selection

Tags: hibernate

In a database consider that I have a table with 4000 rows. I am using JTable to list them in front end. During page load, I need to display only First - 20 rows. I have **NEXT and PREVIOUS button**  in top, so that if I click NEXT button, next 20 rows must be fetched from database and loaded in table.

In short, on button click, I need to fetch a set of values (for example say 20 rows) dynamically from database. I am using Hibernate.

Can anyone suggest me a link or the procedure to do this. 
Any examples will be clear...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ScrollableResults](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html). Take into account that it might be unsupported by some DB drivers.

Or you could use `setFirstResult` and `maxResults`, for example:

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Item.class);
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("name"));
criteria.setFirstResult(100);
criteria.setMaxResults(50);
List pageResults=criteria.list();
```

You may also find the answers to this question useful: [Using Hibernate's ScrollableResults to slowly read 90 million records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826319/using-hibernates-scrollableresults-to-slowly-read-90-million-records)