# Atomic UPDATE .. SELECT in Postgres

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, concurrency, race-condition, transaction-isolation

I'm building a queuing mechanism of sorts. There are rows of data that need processing, and a status flag. I'm using an `update .. returning` clause to manage it:

```
UPDATE stuff
SET computed = 'working'
WHERE id = (SELECT id from STUFF WHERE computed IS NULL LIMIT 1)
RETURNING *
```

Is the nested select part the same lock as the update, or do I have a race condition here? If so, does the inner select need to be a `select for update`?

Comment: If you're trying to build a message queue in sql, and this is any reasonable large volume of tasks, I'm assuming you're eventually going to want to delete the rows for completed jobs.  These will hose your indices, so be sure to vacuum analyze whenever you cleanup the completed tasks or your performance will crawl.  You might want to consider just using an actual message queue (rabbitmq, zeromq, activemq, etc).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

While Erwin's suggestion is possibly the *simplest* way to get correct behavior (so long as you retry your transaction if you get an exception with `SQLSTATE` of 40001), queuing applications by their nature tend to work better with requests blocking for a chance to take their turn at the queue than with the PostgreSQL implementation of `SERIALIZABLE` transactions, which allows higher concurrency and is somewhat more "optimistic" about the chances of collision.

The example query in the question, as it stands, in the default `READ COMMITTED` transaction isolation level would allow two (or more) concurrent connections to both "claim" the same row from the queue.  What will happen is this:

- T1 starts and gets as far as locking the row in the `UPDATE` phase.
- T2 overlaps T1 in execution time and attempts to update that row. It blocks pending the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` of T1.
- T1 commits, having successfully "claimed" the row.
- T2 tries to update the row, finds that T1 already has, looks for the new version of the row, finds that it still satisfies the selection criteria (which is just that `id` matches), and also "claims" the row.

It can be modified to work correctly (if you are using a version of PostgreSQL which allows the `FOR UPDATE` clause in a subquery).  Just add `FOR UPDATE` to the end of the subquery which selects the id, and this will happen:

- T1 starts and now locks the row before *selecting* the id.
- T2 overlaps T1 in execution time and blocks while trying to select an id, pending the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` of T1.
- T1 commits, having successfully "claimed" the row.
- By the time T2 is able to *read* the row to see the id, it sees that it has been claimed, so it finds the next available id.

At the `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level, the write conflict would throw an error, which you could catch and determine was a serialization failure based on the SQLSTATE, and retry.

If you generally want SERIALIZABLE transactions but you want to avoid retries in the queuing area, you might be able to accomplish that by using an [advisory lock](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS).

Comment: Would adding the redundant WHERE clause `AND computed IS NULL` to the outer UPDATE make this particular query behave properly? Or would T2 just come up empty, after T1 has "invalidated" the selected row halfway into the operation?

Comment: In `READ COMMITTED` it would prevent double-assignment, but in the case of overlapping transactions would return an empty result set, even if there were other rows available. At stricter isolation levels it wouldn't make any real difference, but might be good form anyway.

Comment: Thanks again. I devised an alternative solution based on this.

Comment: Note that applications using this strategy must have a way to discover when someone has claimed a row, then crashed or otherwise failed to do the work.

Comment: @CraigRinger makes a good point. Where I have needed to do something somewhat similar to this, I included columns for an identifier of *who* has claimed the row and *when*. This allows cleanup of abandoned claims and some analysis of the cause.

Comment: @kgrittn Can you please make your answer clearer and write the resulting query? You say, "Just add that to the subquery which selects the id", and I have no idea what "that" is. Code is easier to understand than talk. Thanks!

Comment: @Nowaker, I reworded rather than provide an example that was almost exactly like the original -- it seemed to me that people would waste too much time going back and forth to see what the differences were.  Subjective, I know, but this seemed cleaner to me.

Comment: @kgrittn does the statement need to be wrapped in a BEGIN...COMMIT to hold the FOR UPDATE lock?  there's some reports of it not working otherwise:  https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record/pull/79

Comment: @jtomson, most locks are released at the end of the transaction which acquires them (the exception being some advisory locks).  Without a `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` block (or the equivalent using other syntax or an enclosing function), each statement creates its own transaction which is automatically committed or rolled back upon completion of the statement.

Comment: @kgrittn when you say, "At the `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level, the write conflict would throw an error", you mean that there would be a write conflict *unless* `FOR UPDATE` is used, right?

Comment: @Andy `FOR UPDATE` by itself would not prevent the serialization failure, but if you use Erwin's example (for 9.5 and later) that uses `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` with the `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level, then you get exactly what you want without the serialization failure.  There are some ideas floating around to get similar performance for `SERIALIZABLE` transactions if the update has no `ORDER BY` clause and includes a `LIMIT`, but that is just talk at this point.

Answer (score 31):

If you are the **only user**, the query should be fine. In particular, there is no race condition or deadlock within the query itself (between the outer query and the subquery). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES)

> However, a transaction never conflicts with itself.

For **concurrent use**, the matter may be more complicated. You would be on the safe side with [`SERIALIZABLE` transaction mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE):

```sql
BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
UPDATE stuff
SET    computed = 'working'
WHERE  id = (SELECT id FROM stuff WHERE computed IS NULL LIMIT 1)
RETURNING * 
COMMIT;
```

You need to prepare for serialization failures and retry your query in such a case.

But I am not entirely sure if this isn't overkill. I'll ask @kgrittn to stop by .. he is *the* expert with concurrency and serializable transactions ..

[And he did. :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11568880/939860)

#### Best of both worlds

Run the query in default transaction mode `READ COMMITTED`.

For Postgres 9.5 or later use `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`. See:

- [Postgres UPDATE … LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)

For older versions recheck the condition `computed IS NULL` explicitly in the outer `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE stuff
SET    computed = 'working'
WHERE  id = (SELECT id FROM stuff WHERE computed IS NULL LIMIT 1)
AND   computed IS NULL;
```

As @kgrittn's advised in the comment to his answer, this query could come up empty, without having done anything, in the (unlikely) case it got intertwined with a concurrent transaction.

Therefore, it would work much like the first variant in transaction mode `SERIALIZABLE`, you would have to retry - just without the performance penalty.

The only problem: While the conflict is very unlikely because the window of opportunity is just so tiny, it can happen under heavy load. You could not tell for sure whether there are finally no more rows left.

If that does not matter (like in your case), you are done here.
If it does, to be *absolutely sure*, start one more query with [*explicit locking*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) after you get an empty result. If this comes up empty, you are done. If not, continue.
In [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS) it could look like this:

```
LOOP
   UPDATE stuff
   SET    computed = 'working'
   WHERE  id = (SELECT id FROM stuff WHERE computed IS NULL
                LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED);  -- pg 9.5+
   -- WHERE  id = (SELECT id FROM stuff WHERE computed IS NULL LIMIT 1)
   -- AND    computed IS NULL; -- pg 9.4-

   CONTINUE WHEN FOUND;  -- continue outside loop, may be a nested loop

   UPDATE stuff
   SET    computed = 'working'
   WHERE  id = (SELECT id FROM stuff WHERE computed IS NULL
                LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE);

   EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;  -- exit function (end)
END LOOP;
```

That should give you the best of both worlds: performance *and* reliability.

Comment: `SERIALIZABLE` transactions will indeed cause *correct* behavior, but feedback on the new implementation of its implementation in PostgreSQL 9.1 (and later) suggests that queuing applications are a "worst case" scenario. While the technique (call Serializable Snapshot Isolation or SSI) is much faster than using blocking locks for most workloads, I have a report of a 20% performance hit for one particular queuing application, and the reporter (a major PostgreSQL contributor) was able to intentionally engineer worse. So, you could try it, but you might find explicit locking works better.

Comment: I hesitate to make any statement about performance without actually benchmarking it, but I would expect marginally *better* performance (probably small enough to be hard to measure) by just starting with the `UPDATE` in the second block. There are optimizations for a connection re-locking a row it already has locked, and I don't think it would block unless you're in a situation where you'd need the retry anyway.

Comment: in my specific case, this isn't necessary. when the process reaches the end of the queue (as far as it's concerned), it sleeps for 10 minutes and tries again. if a record falls into the next window, it's not an issue. thanks for compiling though.

Comment: @kolosy: The simple version with repeated `AND computed IS NULL` in the outer query should be the optimal solution for such a case.

Comment: For 9.5 and later is `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` all that is needed or is the rest of the paragraph relevant still? The end of the "For older versions" block is not 100% clear.