# Multiple row insert or select if exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, sql-insert

```
CREATE TABLE object (
  object_id serial,
  object_attribute_1 integer,
  object_attribute_2 VARCHAR(255)
)

-- primary key object_id
-- btree index on object_attribute_1, object_attribute_2
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
SELECT * FROM object 
WHERE (object_attribute_1=100 AND object_attribute_2='Some String') OR
(object_attribute_1=200 AND object_attribute_2='Some other String') OR
(..another row..) OR
(..another row..)
```

When the query returns, I check for what is missing (thus, does not exist in the database).

Then I will make an multiple row insert:

```
INSERT INTO object (object_attribute_1, object_attribute_2) 
VALUES (info, info), (info, info),(info, info)
```

Then I will select what I just inserted

`SELECT ... WHERE (condition) OR (condition) OR ...`

And at last, I will merge the two selects on the client side.

Is there a way that I can combine these 3 queries, into one single queries, where I will provide all the data, and `INSERT` if the records do not already exist and then do a `SELECT` in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion was well founded. Do it all in a single statement using a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) (Postgres 9.1+):

```
WITH list(object_attribute_1, object_attribute_2) AS (
   VALUES
      (100, 'Some String')
    , (200, 'Some other String')
    ,  .....
   )
, ins AS (
   INSERT INTO object (object_attribute_1, object_attribute_2)
   SELECT l.*
   FROM   list l
   LEFT   JOIN object o1 USING (object_attribute_1, object_attribute_2)
   WHERE  o1.object_attribute_1 IS NULL
   RETURNING *
   )
SELECT * FROM ins   -- newly inserted rows

UNION ALL           -- append pre-existing rows
SELECT o.*
FROM   list l
JOIN   object o USING (object_attribute_1, object_attribute_2);
```

Note, there is a tiny time frame for a *race condition*. So this might break if many clients try it at the same time. If you are working under heavy concurrent load, consider this related answer, in particular the part on *locking* or [*serializable transaction isolation*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/applevel-consistency.html#SERIALIZABLE-CONSISTENCY):
[Postgresql batch insert or ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890599/postgresql-batch-insert-or-ignore/11892007#11892007)

Comment: I had a feeling that you would come to my postgresql rescue once again. Thank you again! Do you have a twitter account?

Comment: @alumns: Consider the update. My first draft returned only newly inserted rows.