# Update top N values using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I want to update the top 10 values of a column in table. I have three columns; `id`, `account` and `accountrank`. To get the top 10 values I can use the following:

```
SELECT  * FROM accountrecords    
ORDER BY account DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

What I would like to do is to set the value in `accountrank` to be a series of `1 - 10`, based on the magnitude of `account`. Is this possible to do in PostgreSQL?

Comment: If your poatgres version is 8.4 or above, you could use windowing functions + rank() or row_number().

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY account DESC NULLS LAST) AS rn
   FROM   accountrecords    
   ORDER  BY account DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  10
   )
UPDATE accountrecords a
SET    accountrank = cte.rn
FROM   cte
WHERE  cte.id = a.id;
```

Joining in a table expression is typically faster than correlated subqueries. It is also shorter.

With the [window function `row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) distinct numbers are guaranteed. Use `rank()` (or possibly `dense_rank()`) if you want rows with equal values for `account` to share the same number.

Only if there can be `NULL` values in `account`, you need to append [`NULLS LAST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) for descending sort order, or `NULL` values sort on top:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

If there can be concurrent write access, the above query is subject to a **race condition**. Consider:

- [Atomic UPDATE .. SELECT in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11532550/939860)
- [Postgres UPDATE … LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)

However, if that was the case, the whole concept of hard-coding the top ten would be a dubious approach to begin with.

Use a CTE instead of a plain subquery to enforce the `LIMIT` reliably. See links above.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use your select statement in a subquery. Generating the rank-order isn't trivial, but here's at least one way to do it. I haven't tested this, but off the top of my head:

```
update accountrecords
set accountrank =
    (select count(*) + 1 from accountrecords r where r.account > account)
where id in (select id from accountrecords order by account desc limit 10);
```

This has the quirk that if two records have the same value for `account`, then they will get the same rank. You could consider that a feature... :-)