# How to update many rows at once in parallel with postgres query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have the following postgres query that's meant to update all message entries:

`update message m set user_id = u.id from "user" u where u.user_pgid = m.user_pgid`

The trouble is that I have ~300,000,000 message records, and postgres seems to be using only one core for this massive update, causing an IO timeout before the operation can complete.

How do I speed up this simple update command to make it as fast as possible?

the type in the first clause is a UUID, and in the second is i64.

Comment: any other column that identifies each row? are they sequentially generated? if yes, you can update in "chunk" using that PK. like update row with id 1 to 50 then row 51 to 100, etc. you can run all of those query in parallel. oh, dont forget indexes.

Comment: @BagusTesathe _pgid fields are technically `bigserial` type.. so I suppose I could script & chunk it.

Comment: If you have to update every row, you might be better off creating a new fresh table.

Comment: @FrankHeikens how is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Parallel query plans only for `SELECT`

Postgres only uses parallel plans for `SELECT` (and some commands based on a `SELECT`, like `CREATE TABLE AS`.) Queries modifying any rows cannot be parallelized. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html)

> Even when it is in general possible for parallel query plans to be
> generated, the planner will not generate them for a given query if any
> of the following are true:
>
> - The query writes any data or locks any database rows. If a query contains a data-modifying operation either at the top level or within
>   a CTE, no parallel plans for that query will be generated.

#### Manual parallelization

To address what you asked: split up the table into *N* non-overlapping slices along `user_pgid`, roughly equal in size - where *N* is the number of processes to employ in parallel. Should not exceed the number of CPU cores available. In total, stay below the I/O capacity of your DB server.

Create a `PROCEDURE` like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.f_upd_message(
     _lower_incl bigint
   , _upper_excl bigint
   , _step int = 50000
   )
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
DECLARE
   _low bigint;
   _upd_ct int;
BEGIN
   IF _upper_excl <= _lower_incl OR _step < 1 THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION '_upper_excl must be > _lower_inc & _step > 0! Was: _lower_incl: %, _upper_excl: %, _step: %'
                     , _lower_incl, _upper_excl, _step;
   END IF;
   
   FOR _low IN _lower_incl .. _upper_excl - 1 BY _step
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'user_pgid >= % AND user_pgid < %'
                  , _low, LEAST(_upper_excl, _low + _step);  -- optional

      UPDATE public.message m
      SET    user_id = u.id
      FROM   public."user" u
      WHERE  m.user_pgid >= _low
      AND    m.user_pgid <  _low + _step
      AND    m.user_pgid <  _upper_excl  -- enforce upper bound
      AND    u.user_pgid = m.user_pgid
      AND    m.user_id <> u.id;          -- ① suppress empty updates
      
      GET DIAGNOSTICS upd_ct = ROW_COUNT;  -- optional

      COMMIT;

      RAISE NOTICE 'Updated % rows', upd_ct;  -- optional
   END LOOP;
END
$proc$;
```

Call:

```
CALL public.f_upd_message(20000000, 30000000);
```

Or:

```
CALL public.f_upd_message(20000000, 30000000, 100000);
```

① Avoid empty updates (where the column value wouldn't change). If `user_id` can be null, use null-safe comparison with `IS DISTINCT FROM`.
Also prevents repeated updates in case you have to start over or mess up slices. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Base your slices on *actual* min and max `user_pgid`:

```
SELECT min(user_pgid) AS _lower_incl, max(user_pgid) + 1 AS _upper_excl
FROM   public.message;
```

Adjust the `_step` size to your system. I added a default of 50000.

Then run *N* separate sessions each processing one slice. Like, start *N* psql instances (manually or in a shell script).

Each step is **committed**. If you should still run into a timeout (or any other problems), committed work is not rolled back.

Related:

- [Does a procedure run in a transaction in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250376/does-a-procedure-run-in-a-transaction-in-postgresql/28251922#28251922)
- [How to force COMMIT inside function so other sessions can see updated row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391481/how-to-force-commit-inside-function-so-other-sessions-can-see-updated-row/66401602#66401602)

#### Side effects, notes

The table will grow up to twice its size because every update leaves a dead tuple behind. You may want to run `VACUUM FULL` afterwards - **if** you can afford to do so. Alternatively, issue `VACUUM` in the procedure in reasonable intervals to make space from dead tuples available for reuse ...
See:

- [VACUUM returning disk space to operating system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37032/3684)

Various other optimizations are possible. Like drop and later recreate FK constraints, indexes, ... But you absolutely need an **index on `message(user_pgid)`** for this!

**If** you are at liberty to do so, create an updated (sorted?) copy of the table instead of updating all rows. Like [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens) already suggested. That gives you a pristine (clustered) table without bloat.

Comment: This is a lot of new stuff to me :) Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

To speed up the update operation on a large table, you can try a few techniques to optimize the query:

**Batch Processing**
Rather than  updating all records in a single transaction, you can update them in smaller batches. This reduces the impact on system resources and helps avoid timeouts.

sample example implementation of batch processing :

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE 
   batch_size integer := 30000; -- Adjust the batch size as needed
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 0..(SELECT ceil(count(*)::numeric / batch_size) FROM message) LOOP
      UPDATE message m 
      SET user_id = u.id 
      FROM "user" u 
      WHERE u.user_pgid = m.user_pgid 
      LIMIT batch_size 
      OFFSET i * batch_size;
   END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Comment: No `LIMIT` or  `OFFSET` in an `UPDATE` command in Postgres. There are workarounds like https://stackoverflow.com/a/13187601/939860 ...