# Using jsonb_set() for updating specific jsonb array value

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

Currently I am working with PostgreSQL 9.5 and try to update a value inside an array of a jsonb field. But I am unable to get the index of the selected value

My table just looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE samples (
    id serial,
    sample jsonb
 );
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
{"result": [
    {"8410": "ABNDAT", "8411": "Abnahmedatum"},
    {"8410": "ABNZIT", "8411": "Abnahmezeit"},
    {"8410": "FERR_R", "8411": "Ferritin"}
]}
```

My SELECT statement to get the correct value works:

```
SELECT 
    id, value 
FROM 
    samples s, jsonb_array_elements(s.sample#>'{result}') r  
WHERE 
    s.id = 26 and r->>'8410' = 'FERR_R';
```

results in:

```
id | value
----------------------------------------------
26 | {"8410": "FERR_R", "8411": "Ferritin"}
```

Ok, this is what I wanted. Now I want to execute an update using the following UPDATE statement to add a new element "ratingtext" (if not already there):

```
UPDATE 
    samples s
SET
    sample = jsonb_set(sample,
              '{result,2,ratingtext}',
              '"Some individual text"'::jsonb,
              true)
WHERE
      s.id = 26;
```

After executing the UPDATE statement, my data looks like this (also correct):

```
{"result": [
    {"8410": "ABNDAT", "8411": "Abnahmedatum"},
    {"8410": "ABNZIT", "8411": "Abnahmezeit"},
    {"8410": "FERR_R", "8411": "Ferritin", "ratingtext": "Some individual text"}
]}
```

So far so good, but I **manually** searched the index value of 2 to get the right element inside the JSON array. If the order will be changed, this won't work.

**So my problem:**

Is there a way to get the index of the selected JSON array element and combine the SELECT statement and the UPDATE statement into one?

Just like:

```
UPDATE 
    samples s
SET
    sample = jsonb_set(sample,
              '{result,' || INDEX OF ELEMENT || ',ratingtext}',
              '"Some individual text"'::jsonb,
              true)
WHERE
      s.id = 26;
```

The values of *samples.id* and *"8410"* are known before preparing the statement.

Or is this not possible at the moment?

Comment: Similar question/answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193390/update-nth-element-of-array-using-a-where-clause

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can find an index of a searched element using `jsonb_array_elements() with ordinality` (note, `ordinality` starts from 1 while the first index of json array is 0):

```
select 
    pos- 1 as elem_index
from 
    samples, 
    jsonb_array_elements(sample->'result') with ordinality arr(elem, pos)
where
    id = 26 and
    elem->>'8410' = 'FERR_R';

 elem_index 
------------
          2
(1 row)
```

Use the above query to update the element based on its index (note that the second argument of `jsonb_set()` is a text array):

```
update 
    samples
set
    sample = 
        jsonb_set(
            sample,
            array['result', elem_index::text, 'ratingtext'],
            '"some individual text"'::jsonb,
            true)
from (
    select 
        pos- 1 as elem_index
    from 
        samples, 
        jsonb_array_elements(sample->'result') with ordinality arr(elem, pos)
    where
        id = 26 and
        elem->>'8410' = 'FERR_R'
    ) sub
where
    id = 26;
```

Result:

```
select id, jsonb_pretty(sample)
from samples;

 id |                   jsonb_pretty                   
----+--------------------------------------------------
 26 | {                                               +
    |     "result": [                                 +
    |         {                                       +
    |             "8410": "ABNDAT",                   +
    |             "8411": "Abnahmedatum"              +
    |         },                                      +
    |         {                                       +
    |             "8410": "ABNZIT",                   +
    |             "8411": "Abnahmezeit"               +
    |         },                                      +
    |         {                                       +
    |             "8410": "FERR_R",                   +
    |             "8411": "Ferritin",                 +
    |             "ratingtext": "Some individual text"+
    |         }                                       +
    |     ]                                           +
    | }
(1 row)
```

The last argument in `jsonb_set()` should be `true` to force adding a new value if its key does not exist yet. It may be skipped however as its default value is `true`.

Though concurrency issues seem to be unlikely (due to the restrictive WHERE condition and a potentially small number of affected rows) you may be also interested in [Atomic UPDATE .. SELECT in Postgres.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532550/atomic-update-select-in-postgres)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works like a charme! I did not realize, that I can use the **elem** in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks klin, this just saved my day !

Comment: Nicely explained by breaking it down into sections, this deserves more upvotes for sure

Comment: @klin, one thing missing may be the potential concurrency issues, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497, also why use `true` in `jsonb_set` ?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy - thanks, I've added the appropriate notes.