# Postgres operator "-" is not removing text element from jsonb array

Tags: postgresql

`images` column is type jsonb.

[Reading Postgres docs on the - operator for text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) it states:

> Delete key/value pair or string element from left operand. Key/value pairs are matched based on their key value.

However, I am not having success. After I run my update I see the element in the array still exists. Is this because it is the only element in the array? If so, how would I deal with such a situation?

```
dev_dolphin_db=#  update listings set images = images - 'filename' where listings.id = 2;
UPDATE 1
```

---

```
id               | 2
created_at       | 2017-04-20 04:19:41.009022+00
posted_by        | 101090922
images           | [{"review": "/9j/4AAQSC1LnS//2Q==", "filename": "3/2/image-3-2-1492661981049.jpeg"}]
```

Comment: The top level element in `images` is an _array_ not a JSON object. The `-` operator does not work with arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hash is consistently in the 0th index of the jsonb array, you can delete it with

```
dev_dolphin_db=#  update listings set images = images #- '{0,filename}' where listings.id = 2;
```

This uses the `#-` operator which postgres describes as:

```
Delete the field or element with specified path (for JSON arrays, negative integers count from the end)
```

Comment: It won't always be the 0th index. Any idea how I can find out which index? I took another look at the manual and didn't see any jsonb function or operator to return a index

Comment: This looks like a viable strategy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996212/postgresql-9-5-jsonb-set-getting-index-of-json-array