# How to update JSON node that matches criteria based on attribute value (instead of index)?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json

Postgresql 10+

Example from the documentation...

```
jsonb_set('[{"f1":1,"f2":null},2,null,3]', '{0,f1}','[2,3,4]', false)
```

results in...

```
[{"f1":[2,3,4],"f2":null},2,null,3]
```

Fair enough. But I need to find my target node by attribute value, not index. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how do something like...

```
jsonb_set('[{"f1":1,"f2":null},2,null,3]', '{(where f1 = 1),f1}','[2,3,4]', false)
```

Any advice on how to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Comment: [postgresql 9.5 using jsonb_set for updating specific jsonb array value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38996212/1995738)

Answer (score 2):

You can split the steps into two jobs:

1. Split in elements (jsonb_arral_elements)
2. Indentify wich elements must change (case when...)
3. Update that element (jsonb_set)
4. Join all together (jsonb_agg)

**solution**

```
select jsonb_agg(case when element->>'f1'='1' then jsonb_set(element, '{f1}', '[2,3,4]') else element end)
  from jsonb_array_elements('[{"f1":1,"f2":null},2,null,3,{"f1":3},{"f1":1,"f2":2}]'::jsonb) element
```

*note*

I changed the input adding two more elements with "f1" key

Comment: Thank you for your response. That does indeed change the json, however, I don't see that it provides a means to update the record. Maybe it's my fault for not making it clear that that's what I needed. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like to me like I *must* get the item index in order to change the item while keeping the whole node. The link posted by @klin works. Kind of verbose and convoluted, but so far, the only thing that works for me.

Comment: @JimOtt, you can use it in an update statement. See at: http://rextester.com/BLC52070