# Insert element in JSONB Array - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, jsonb, postgresql-10

Let's say I have a table:

```
SELECT * FROM settings;
| id | name    | strategies |
| -- | ---     | ---        |
| 1  | default | [{name: xyz, enabled: true}, {name: bot2, enabled: true}]  |
| 2  | new1    | [{name: bot2, enabled: true}, {name: xyz, enabled: false}] |
```

I want to add a new object `{name: bot1, enabled: true}` before `bot2`.

I'm trying to use a solution from [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996212/postgresql-9-5-using-jsonb-set-for-updating-specific-jsonb-array-value):

```
WITH bot2_index AS (SELECT
    pos- 1 AS bot2_index
FROM
    settings, 
    jsonb_array_elements(strategies) WITH ordinality arr(elem, pos)
WHERE
    NAME = 'default'
    AND elem->>'name' = 'bot2')    
UPDATE settings
SET strategies = jsonb_set(strategies, '{bot2_index}', '{
  "name": "bot1",
  "enabled": false
}', TRUE);
```

but I get

```
ERROR:  path element at position 1 is not an integer: "bot2_index"
```

`bot2_index` is of type `bigint` so why this syntax doesn't work?

I've also tried other variations like just `bot2_index`, `bot2_index::int`, `bot2_index::string`, or even run it as two separate queries (like in the accepted answer) but it doesn't work either.

**EDIT #1**

This syntax works, but it seems to replace the element at that index, rather than appending the element before or after the element at given index - how can I make it work like JS `splice()` function?

```
UPDATE settings
SET strategies = jsonb_set(strategies, concat('{',(SELECT
    pos- 1 AS bot2_index
FROM
    settings, 
    jsonb_array_elements(strategies) WITH ordinality arr(elem, pos)
WHERE
    NAME = 'default'
    AND elem->>'name' = 'js:bot2'),'}')::text[], '{
  "name": "bot1",
  "enabled": false
}', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all for your current query you should use it like below:

```
WITH bot2_index AS (SELECT
    pos- 1 AS bot2_index
FROM
    settings, 
    jsonb_array_elements(strategies) WITH ordinality arr(elem, pos)
WHERE
    name = 'default'
    AND elem->>'name' = 'bot2')    
        
UPDATE settings
SET strategies = jsonb_set(strategies, array[bot2_index::text], '{
  "name": "bot1",
  "enabled": false
}'::jsonb, false) from bot2_index;
```

**But query will replace the existing one**
[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n6xkAYRvnjWpAH3HQLrq1a/3)

You should use `jsonb_insert` for it instead of `jsonb_set`.

```
WITH bot2_index AS (SELECT
    pos- 1 AS bot2_index
FROM
    settings, 
    jsonb_array_elements(strategies) WITH ordinality arr(elem, pos)
WHERE
    name = 'default'
    AND elem->>'name' = 'bot2')    
        
UPDATE settings
SET strategies = jsonb_insert(strategies, array[bot2_index::text], '{
  "name": "bot1",
  "enabled": false
}'::jsonb, false) from bot2_index;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n6xkAYRvnjWpAH3HQLrq1a/5)

Comment: please check now