# The correct way to atomically update field in Postgres based on its current value

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

I have a table `my_table` in PostgreSQL v 12 which has two fields called `id` and `status`.
I need to write a stored procedure `updateStatus` which has three parameters (`id`, `oldStatus` and `newStatus`). It should update the row's status to `newStatus` only if it is in `oldStatus` at the moment and (do something else otherwise like throwing an exception). The procedure should work well in concurrent mode.
What is the best way to achieve this?
I thought of the way suggested here: [Atomic UPDATE .. SELECT in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532550/atomic-update-select-in-postgres)

Is it OK? Or perhaps there is an easier way to achieve the same effect?

```
LOOP
   UPDATE my_table
   SET    status = _new_status_
   WHERE  id = (SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id = _id_ status = _old_status
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED);  -- pg 9.5

   CONTINUE WHEN FOUND; 

   UPDATE my_table
   SET    status = _new_status_
   WHERE  id = (SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id = _id_ and status = _old_status
                FOR UPDATE);

   EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;  -- throw some error perhaps etc
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Your WHERE clause seems overly complicated. A simple `where id = _id_ and status = _old_status` seems enough - unless `id` isn't a unique column

Comment: I've removed the `limit 1` clause but do I need those for update and skip locked clauses?

Comment: This is a traditional implementation of Optimistic Locking. There's plenty of documentation about it, and at least three strategies to implement it. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: The problem is to choose the best way. I know what I would have done in the Oracle world but I do not know the best way do it in the PostgreSQL world. If the "select for update" way is OK, I'll stick to it as it's the most readable one, I think

Comment: No one can tell you *the best way* because what is best in my environment may not be so in yours. The **only** way for you to know which *is best* is to test them in your environment.  Keep in mind however that the best way may change over time and volume.