# How to ensure sum of amounts in one table is less than the amount of another?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

Say I have a table of marbles

| id | color | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 5 |
| 2 | red | 10 |
| 3 | swirly | 3 |

and I need to put them into bags with a unique constraint on `(bag_id, marble_id)`:

| bag_id | marble_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 (blue) | 2 |
| 1 | 2 (red) | 3 |
| 2 | 1 (blue) | 2 |

I have a query for bagging at most the number of remaining marbles

```sql
WITH unbagged AS (
  SELECT
    marble.total - COALESCE( SUM( bag.quantity ), 0 ) AS quantity
  FROM marble
    LEFT JOIN bag ON marble.id = bag.marble_id
  WHERE marble.id = :marble_id
  GROUP BY marble.id )
  
INSERT INTO bag (bag_id, marble_id, quantity)
SELECT
  :bag_id,
  :marble_id,
  LEAST( :quantity, unbagged.quantity )
FROM unbagged
ON CONFLICT (bag_id, marble_id) DO UPDATE SET
  quantity = bag.quantity
    + LEAST(
        EXCLUDED.quantity,
        (SELECT quantity FROM unbagged) )
```

which works great until one day, it gets called twice at exactly the same time with the same item and I end up with 6 swirly marbles in a bag (or maybe 3 each in 2 bags), even though there are only 3 total.

I think I understand why, but I don't know how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm isn't exactly clear to me, but the core issue is [**concurrency**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html).

#### Manual locking

Your query processes a single given row in table `marble` at a time. The cheapest solution is to take an [exclusive lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES) on that row (assuming that's the only query writing to `marble` and `bag`). Then the next transaction trying to mess with the same kind of marble has to wait until the current one has committed (or rolled back).

```sql
BEGIN;

SELECT FROM marble WHERE id = :marble_id FOR UPDATE;  -- row level lock

WITH unbagged AS ( ...

COMMIT;
```

#### `SERIALIZABLE`

Or use [serializable transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE), that's the more expensive "catch-all" solution - and be prepared to repeat the transaction in case of a serialization error. Like:

```sql
BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

WITH unbagged AS ( ...

COMMIT;
```

Related:

- [How to atomically replace a subset of table data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166912/3684)
- [Atomic UPDATE .. SELECT in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532550/atomic-update-select-in-postgres/11533623)

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking the lock had to happen on the bag, but wasn't sure how to do that for a row that may not yet exist. It hadn't occurred to me to lock the marble instead.

Comment: @zakm: Postgres has no provision for predicate locking (locking based upon logical conditions rather than existing rows/objects) in the user realm.