# Reading from a very large table using multiple threads (Java ) and writing them to a single file

Tags: java, multithreading, large-data

I am currently facing a situation where i have a table with almost 80 millions data and i have to take a dump of that table and store it into a csv file. Currently i am using a not so professional approach( with a perl script+DBI interface , printing the values to stdout and redirecting to a csv file). Now i am planning to use java threading approach. Can you suggest a way forward. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? What benefits do you expect from using Java and multiple threads?

Comment: how exactly do you plan to gain anything from MT writing to a file? are all rows of the exact same length?

Comment: What you're trying to do is completely I/O-bound. There will be no performance gain by multithreading. I guess Java will not be significantly faster than perl in this case ... if you did your perl script right, it can be a professional solution.

Comment: you have to do this periodically, isn't it?

Comment: U will require some R&D over it.. though using Thread Pool may help you where some number of threads will take care of your entire data in batch and write them in file..

Comment: I am not sticking to perl approach because i am trying to utilize my hardware a bit .(Exalogic+Exadata Quarter stack) . And i am actually printing the values in stdout and redirecting to a file which seems very very unprofessional. And in many cases ( disconnected from lan/wifi) i dont even get any error notification and i am left out with an incomplete file. And yeah the rows are of equal length. Thread Pool seems like a solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement several threads in Java for downloading a single table data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325745/how-to-implement-several-threads-in-java-for-downloading-a-single-table-data)

Comment: All the databases I've used come with a dump utility. You don't have to write code for this.