# What is a LAC record?

Tags: java, database, definition, vocabulary

Could please explained what is a "lac record" in the context of Java & Databases.

I've seen references for "lac record" with a table having 12 lacs records
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325745/how-to-implement-several-threads-in-java-for-downloading-a-single-table-data)

I can't figure out the meaning of "lac record"...

Thanks

Comment: As in the linked question, "1 lac = 100,000". It's a term mostly used in India, as far as I understand. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh. Not a computing technical term at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (as it turns out) it's not a programming term being discussed.

Comment: It seems to be the case, thanks. Please find another reference [here](http://www.oraclesolved.com/general/Q_25470599-Fast-Insertion-of-5-lac-record-using-java.jsp)

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that 'lac' is the Indian word for a number (100,000) usually spelt lakh (I think - maybe lahk). That makes sense in the context of the link.