# Efficient criteria query to only select the first and last result of a query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a query on a large data set with an order by. I am only interested in the first and last row. It's very easy to get the first result (using `Criteria.setMaxResult()`) and I can get the last one by reversing the order by.

However, to get both of them seems to require two queries which may not be very efficient with the database. Since this is very easy to achieve with SQL, I am wondering how to formulate an advanced criteria query that can get both of them in one go?

Please do no suggest retrieving all of them and get the first and last element of the list because the dataset is very large and it takes minutes to read all of them from the database.

I hope this query can be database independent, but if that is not easy, then assume the target database is Oracle.

Comment: You can just change your query to return the two items you need. Then  you don't have to do the large fetching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [`ScrollableResults`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html):

```
Criteria criteria = ...;
ScrollableResults scroll = criteria.scroll();
Object[] firstRow = scroll.get();  // or use other methods for getting the data
scroll.last();
Object[] lastRow = scroll.get();
```

Note that this [can take even longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826319/using-hibernates-scrollableresults-to-slowly-read-90-million-records) than running two queries. But it depends on the database you're using.