# Hibernate pagination mechanism

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, pagination

I am trying to use Hibernate pagination for my query (PostgreSQL )

I set `setFirstResult(0)`, `setMaxResults(20)` for my SQL query. My code is like below:

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Customers");
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(20);
List<T> entities = query.list();
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

but when viewing the SQL Hibernate log, I still see the full SQL query:

```
Hibernate: select customer0_.id as id9_, customer0_.customer_name as dst2_9_, customer0_.addres as dst3_9_ from tbl_customers customer0_
```

Why there is no LIMIT OFFSET in query of Hibernate pagination SQL log?

Does anyone know about Hibernate pagination mechanism?

I guess that Hibernate will select all data, put data into Resultset, and then paging in Resultset, right?

Comment: Nope Hibernate does not do that and it tries to apply pagination in query-level. I believe it's a dialect problem, are you sure that you have set Postgre dialect in Hibernate config?

Comment: By the ways, is this SQL or HQL? You must pass an HQL to `createQuery` method.

Comment: In this example, i am using: Hibernate Query Examples (HQL)

Comment: has this been solved since?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am using in query and in hibernate  call back. both are working as expected. Hibernate Query executes for results in between First and Max size given. Here Seems like you passed SQL not HQL to query. if yes it shouldn't work.

-- See my code here.

```
        Query query = this.getSession().createQuery("FROM QueryType");
        query.setFirstResult(0);
        query.setMaxResults(20);
        List toDelete = query.list();
```

and in log:

select
        * 
    from
        ( select
            -- ALL column names. (dont want to share here.)
        from
            MY_TBL_NAME querytype0_ ) 
    where
        rownum <= ?

Comment: I am using Hibernate Query Examples (HQL) (I updated my code ), not Native SQL. It still show log query all.

Answer (score 13):

There are quite a few ways to paginate.

**HQL and setFirstResult, setMaxResults API**

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("From Foo");
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(10);
List<Foo> fooList = query.list();
//Total count
String countQ = "Select count (f.id) from Foo f";
Query countQuery = session.createQuery(countQ);
Long countResults = (Long) countQuery.uniqueResult();
//Last Page
int pageSize = 10;
int lastPageNumber = (int) ((countResult / pageSize) + 1);
```

**HQL and the ScrollableResults API**

```
String hql = "FROM Foo f order by f.name";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
int pageSize = 10;

ScrollableResults resultScroll = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
resultScroll.first();
resultScroll.scroll(0);
List<Foo> fooPage = Lists.newArrayList();
int i = 0;
while (pageSize > i++) {
    fooPage.add((Foo) resultScroll.get(0));
    if (!resultScroll.next())
        break;
}
//Total count
resultScroll.last();
int totalResults = resultScroll.getRowNumber() + 1;
```

**Simply the Criteria API**

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
criteria.setFirstResult(0);
criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
List<Foo> firstPage = criteria.list();
//Total count
Criteria criteriaCount = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
criteriaCount.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
Long count = (Long) criteriaCount.uniqueResult();
```

[baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-pagination) lists them all with examples.

Comment: Your example using ScrollableResults API will read eveything into the memory. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826319/using-hibernates-scrollableresults-to-slowly-read-90-million-records). You can make it work as explained there by @Sean S. but it definitely does not offer a straightforward solution.

Comment: RDBMS dependent and **not** all RDBMS has this problem. Good to know, but that wasn't the original poster's question/concern

Comment: Using the `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` method why you didn't add the `Order By`? Hibernate will automatically fetch the data in the same way everytime?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the JPA pagination for both entity queries and native SQL.

To limit the underlying query `ResultSet` size, the JPA `Query` interface provides the [`setMaxResults` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults-int-).

Navigating the following page requires positioning the result set where the last page ended. For this purpose, the JPA `Query` interface provides the [`setFirstResult` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setFirstResult-int-).

### JPQL

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select p
    from Post p
    order by p.createdOn
    """, Post.class)
.setFirstResult(10)
.setMaxResults(10)
.getResultList();
```

### DTO projection queries

The JPA query pagination is not limited to entity queries that return entities only. You can use it for DTO projections as well.

```
List<PostCommentSummary> summaries = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select new
       com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.fetching.PostCommentSummary(
           p.id, p.title, c.review
       )
    from PostComment c
    join c.post p
    order by c.createdOn
    """)
.setMaxResults(10)
.getResultList();
```

### Native SQL queries

The JPA query pagination is not limited to entity queries, such as JPQL or Criteria API. You can use it for native SQL queries as well.

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    where p.title like :titlePattern
    order by p.createdOn
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("titlePattern", "High-Performance Java Persistence %")
.setMaxResults(5)
.getResultList();
```

### JOIN FETCH and pagination

However, if we try to use the `JOIN FETCH` clause in the entity query while also using JPA pagination:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    where p.title like :titlePattern
    order by p.createdOn
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("titlePattern", "High-Performance Java Persistence %")
.setMaxResults(5)
.getResultList();
```

Hibernate will issue the following warning message:

```
HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
```

And the executed SQL query will lack the pagination clause:

```
SELECT p.id AS id1_0_0_,
       c.id AS id1_1_1_,
       p.created_on AS created_2_0_0_,
       p.title AS title3_0_0_,
       c.created_on AS created_2_1_1_,
       c.post_id AS post_id4_1_1_,
       c.review AS review3_1_1_,
       c.post_id AS post_id4_1_0__,
       c.id AS id1_1_0__
FROM post p
LEFT OUTER JOIN post_comment c ON p.id=c.post_id
WHERE p.title LIKE :titlePattern
ORDER BY p.created_on
```

This is because Hibernate wants to fetch entities fully along with their collections as indicated by the `JOIN FETCH` clause while the SQL-level pagination could truncate the `ResultSet` possibly leaving a parent `Post` entity with fewer elements in the `comments` collection.

The problem with the `HHH000104` warning is that Hibernate will fetch the product of `Post` and `PostComment` entities, and due to the result set size, the query response time is going to be significant.

In order to work around this limitation, you have to use a [Window Function](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-definitely-learn-sql-window-functions/) query:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "PostWithCommentByRank",
    query = """
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT
                *,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                    ORDER BY "p.created_on", "p.id"
                ) rank
            FROM (
                SELECT
                    p.id AS "p.id", p.created_on AS "p.created_on",
                    p.title AS "p.title", pc.post_id AS "pc.post_id",
                    pc.id as "pc.id", pc.created_on AS "pc.created_on",
                    pc.review AS "pc.review"
                FROM  post p
                LEFT JOIN post_comment pc ON p.id = pc.post_id
                WHERE p.title LIKE :titlePattern
                ORDER BY p.created_on
            ) p_pc
        ) p_pc_r
        WHERE p_pc_r.rank <= :rank
        """,
    resultSetMapping = "PostWithCommentByRankMapping"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "PostWithCommentByRankMapping",
    entities = {
        @EntityResult(
            entityClass = Post.class,
            fields = {
                @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "p.id"),
                @FieldResult(name = "createdOn", column = "p.created_on"),
                @FieldResult(name = "title", column = "p.title"),
            }
        ),
        @EntityResult(
            entityClass = PostComment.class,
            fields = {
                @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "pc.id"),
                @FieldResult(name = "createdOn", column = "pc.created_on"),
                @FieldResult(name = "review", column = "pc.review"),
                @FieldResult(name = "post", column = "pc.post_id"),
            }
        )
    }
)
```

> For more details about using Window Functions to fix the `HHH000104` issue as well as the code for [`DistinctPostResultTransformer`](https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/).