# How to fetch records in pagination using hibernate queries and struts

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, pagination, struts2

In pagination I am having `1000 records` but by default it should load only 1`00 records` first and remaining should not load until I fetch those records from database.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: use https://www.google.co.in/

Comment: google.co.in? - santosh gore

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: use http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/example-on-hibernate-pagination-with-servlet-in-eclipse/ url for reference.

Comment: @sana remove this comment to the question

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. In each pagination setFirstResult will be changed.
Using:

```
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(100);
```

Duplicate of [hibernate pagination mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649194/hibernate-pagination-mechanism)

Comment: thank you for reply, even i tried it but its just showing only 100 records. so, how can i fetch remaining records from 101 to 1000 ...this is my problem

Comment: For second page, you need to change FirstResult set to 100. E.g. for second page query.setFirstResult(100); again next page  query.setFirstResult(200);. But the MaxResults will be the same 100 as you want to fetch maximum 100 records each time.

Comment: i tried it here but no result of using setFirstResult()

Comment: This is not the way to make pagination. For first request, you need to have query.setFirstResult(0); query.setMaxResults(100); For second request you need to have query.setFirstResult(100); query.setMaxResults(100); For third request query.setFirstResult(200); query.setMaxResults(100); and so on...

Comment: how we will write first request, second request and so on .. can u give an example?

Comment: Example like: in UI side you have JSP and in Backend you have Servlet and for DAO layer you have Hibernate. Now suppose you are fetching employee records by pagination. In down of the employee table grid, previous and next link is there. For first page FirstResult as 0 sent from UI. While you click Next link you need to send page value is 1 and in hibernate side you need to set FirstResult as (1+100), here 1 is the page value and 100 is the MaxResults and make it (1+100)-1, here means FirstResult you set as 100. So FirstResult should be dynamic as input and here I am getting the input from UI.