# Iterating over ScrollableResults vs ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, resultset

In our Queries we have large resultsets. We want to implement a streaming mechanic like:

```
//repeat split times
for( int i = 0 ; i < split ; i++){
    //Fetch some records
    //Send fetched records
    //continue at next cursorposition
}
```

Now this works well for:

```
results = query.scroll();
```

But due to some circumstances we may need to work with a ResultSet from

```
ResultSet results = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

I can now also iterate also over the ResultSet:

```
results.next()
```

Now afaik:
The ScrollableResults does the recordfetching depending on the cursorposition, which would mean, i could send data already while more data is being fetched.

The ResultSet already fetches the complete data at once, and i could start with the sending of data only afterwards.

My Question is, am i right with this assuming, or does the ResultSet.next() work similar to the ScorllableResults.next()?

Background is: I want to be able to send some required data, before the complete resultset is being fetched (processed).

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826319/using-hibernates-scrollableresults-to-slowly-read-90-million-records