# Hibernate List vs. JDBC ResultSet

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Hibernate is very good for **code readability** and  **database portability**

However I realize that Hibernate takes a lot of memory. Here is an example

**HIBERNATE VERSION**

```
 String hql = "FROM Employee";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    List results = query.list(); // this list is limited my the size of my RAM
```

**JDBC VERSION**

```
ResultSet resSet = connection.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Employee"); 
while (resSet.next()) { 
// This resSet is not limited to my RAM
}
```

So if I have a query that returns hundreds of thousands of rows, I should better handle it with JDBC, because then I can process each row sequentially, and this does not take all my RAM.

**Am I correct? Or does Hibernate have any sort of "streaming List" similar to ResultSet object that does not "flood" RAM ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ScrollableResults](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html) to get the results from hibernate row by row. There are examples in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826319/using-hibernates-scrollableresults-to-slowly-read-90-million-records).

Answer (score 0):

Read a little bit hibernate official web:

http://hibernate.org/orm/

Answering you, there is not possible hibernate (maybe with native query  https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/) take less memory or time process than JDBC because hibernate is a abstraction of JPA and JDBC, so it was built to help developers to programming faster and easily but it will cost more resources to process it