# Are using div tags faster than using table tr and td tags for tabular data of huge size?

Tags: php, html, css, sql, html-table

I have a huge table loading from remote aws ec2 server through php scripts accessing a postgres database.
Currently, there are 2000 rows with 20 columns in the table, taking about 2 min to load after all query optimizations and using multidimensional php arrays to store data for all members through a single query instead of querying the database every now and then for each of the 2000 users.

I was able to reduce the loading time from 5 min to 2 min.

My question is, does the UI also needs to be optimized? Is the traditional table tag outdated? Which is the best way to go about?

Suppose i have all the data ready. If I need to put them out to display instantly, in huge numbers, which is the best way to do it?

I'm not very well versed with HTML or CSS or even UI testing.

Comment: *My question is, does the UI also needs to be optimized?* it depends whether you used multiple nesting loops or not, it may incur a lot cpu loads. * Is the traditional table tag outdated?*, no its [still within HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-table-element.html), no issue. this **taking about 2 min to load** is it the whole page loading or the query itself? you might run into unoptimized js/css, like compiling less on client side.

Comment: Maybe you can try to query in your result in batches. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676777/how-to-select-all-the-table-records-in-batches-and-process-each-batch

Comment: @BagusTesa I use printf in a loop which iterates 2000 times, one time for printing each row of the table. I have already stored all the data from sql query results in php multidimensional arrays. When I load the php page, initially for 5 seconds, there would be no output. Then, it will suddenly start populating the table from the top. If you scroll down while it's loading, you can see how many rows it has loaded at this moment. So, it's actually the UI which is taking up the major portion of loading time.
Gosi, I am already querying and storing my result in PHP arrays. It takes just 5 secs

Comment: *When I load the php page, initially for 5 seconds, there would be no output. Then, it will suddenly start populating the table from the top. If you scroll down while it's loading* do you have some ajax doing the table rendering? could you check on browser console's network tab to be sure?

Comment: I don't use any ajax. Pure PHP. No APIs, nothing. I store all the output from the postgreSQL query into separate 2d arrays with keys corresponding to the users and their attributes. The values will be the individual results and calculations in SQL queries and PHP scripts. After all this is done, only then I start the foreach loop to printf the rows one by one and their corresponding values against the user IDs.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, UI and HTML optimization **will not make a real difference** in terms of loading time.

I would recommend you to measure the time your webpage takes to load the complete table, but **step by step**. Put "*echo*" commands in your code to divide the full process in little tasks, then you will see where you have to put more effort in terms of timing.

How much time does my program take to...

- ...connect to my remote server?
- ...receive the raw data from my remote server?
- ...process the data for the presentation in the next step?
- ...present the processed data on the webpage?

Then you will see that the last step, the UI-related step, is not that relevant (think that for example PHPMyAdmin can show you thousands of rows in seconds).

In any case, HTML tables will be the fastest way as they are more "simple" than DIVs. Try to preconfigurate all the CSS you can so your browser will not need to calculate it!

Answer (score 0):

HTML tables aren't outdated at all! :) They're the fastest and most semantic way to display tables of data.

If you need to micro-optimize, I speculate that it might be fastest to use fixed column widths (avoiding dynamic resizing). Other ideas: something in JS that "streamed" the data onto the page (avoiding rerendering), use PHP's output buffering functions, or maybe look into exporting/importing CSV for managing huge datasets? ;)