# how to select specific columns in hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I need to select only few columns using hibernate search. Following is the code which works fine

```
  FullTextSession fts = org.hibernate.search.Search.getFullTextSession(getSession());

  org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery query = prepareQuery(dto);
  fullTextQuery = fts.createFullTextQuery(query, ProfileBean.class);

  fullTextQuery.setFirstResult(dto.getProfileBean().getResultStartIndex());
  fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(dto.getProfileBean().getResultsLimit());

  List<ProfileBean> profiles = fullTextQuery.list();
```

In the above case I only want to select columns 'firstName' and 'lastName'.

Following code throws an exception

```
 List<String> projectedFields = new ArrayList<String>();
          projectedFields.add("firstName");
          projectedFields.add("lastName");

org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Projecting an unstored field: firstName
```

actually i don't want to store the firstName field in lucene any other suggession.?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652358/how-do-you-select-a-column-using-hibernate?rq=1

Comment: thanks for your reply. but above code doesn't work with hibernate search.

Answer (score 1):

In your class ProfileBean, you'll need to add annotation:

```
@Field(store=Store.YES)
```

to fields `firstname`, `lastname`

Please find section 5.1.2.5. Projection in Hibernate documentation for details:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en/html/search-query.html#d0e3643

Happy coding!