# Retrieve specific column wihtout mapping - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I am working on a Java `Hibernate` project and I want to retrieve information from tables.I use XML mapping to link a table with an class(entity) as you know ,though for another table I want to retrieve only one column by native `sql` without doing the unnecessary XML mapping or the annotation, like jdbc does but without adding additional .java files.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652358/how-do-you-select-a-column-using-hibernate

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful I missed this question, do you know if it does need mapping, I shall try it and see.

Comment: Good method,but from what I am aware you have to still create the class entity.